# Conflict in jQuery functions

Tags: jquery

The following jQuery function works fine:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mytags").tagit({
            availableTags: ["c++", "java"],
        });
    });
    </script>
```

If I try to combine another function in the above code, only first one works, but the second does not work. For example, in the code below, the second function doesn't work, but it was working fine above. If i place it first, then it works fine but the other doesn't.

```
    $("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'uploadify/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
        'script': 'uploadify/upload.php'

            });

$("#mytags").tagit({
            availableTags: ["c++", "java"]          
        });
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you open the console and let me know what the actual error by the JavaScript console? It's likely abc is not defined.

Comment: is there any javascript error in first call? and what is `abc` doing? What do you mean by not working? Any JS error? Or first function is changing the dom which may result in second one breaking

Comment: @Gcoop , Im using notepad, how can I find the error message? Basically the tagit function displays the input field, but it does not display.

Comment: use the firebug plugin for Firefox browser and see if there are any javascript errros.

Comment: @Teja Kantamneni, I just solved it. The problem was only that I was including jQuery liberary two times by mistake. Thank you for introducing the Firebug, its great.

Answer (score 1):

Is this actual code? It doesn't work because `.abc` isn't a real function, so it errors and doesn't ever reach the second function.

Comment: thanks for reply. I edited the question and added the orignal functions. Both functions work fine separately (if i use only one function), but if I try to add both functions only first one works.